# Solving $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt[3]{x^3-5x^2+1}-x)$ with series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

In "Problem-Solving Through Problems" from Loren C Larson , there is a problem (5-4-30) that says find the below limit with infinite series .
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt[3]{x^3-5x^2+1}-x)$$ this is easy limitation, but **what is the idea to solving with  infinite series?**

I don't have a clue. I thankful for any hint in advance.

Comment: Google "Taylor expansion" -- this should help.

Comment: @ClementC. Taylor expansion around what point?

Comment: @Masacroso "Every Taylor expansion ought to be around $0$." (Clément, 2017). Joke aside: around $0$. Factor out $x$, and expand with regard to $1/x$ which goes to $0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @ClementC. What do you mean "expand with regard to $1/x$"? Do you mean to write the series as $a_0 + a_1/x + a_2/x^2 + \cdots$? Because that's commonly known as an expansion around $\infty$.

Comment: @ClementC. Taylor expansion series are not really "infinite".

Comment: @Arthur My point is: you only need to ever care about expansions *around $0$*, which are standard and easy to know and compose. (Also, the theory and theorems about Taylor expansions are usually given around $0$). Then, by a simple change of variables as the above ($h=1/x$ for instance), that's all you need to worry about.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I know, but I assume that's what the book cited meant. I will try to get my hands on it to see if there was an actual intent to use the full infintie series representation, but somehow I doubt it.

Comment: I can't find this problem in the book, which page is it ?

Comment: It's 5.4.30, not 30.4.5. @LeGrandDODOM (I was puzzled too). Looking at a similar exercise (5.4.3), I now **strongly** suspect the authors really meant Taylor expansions to some low order indeed.

Comment: @ClementC : I would like to quote you in future whenever needed :) Frankly speaking I never liked the series in powers of $(x-a)$ rather I prefer the old school Taylor series for $f(a+h) $ in powers of $h$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = \frac{1}{x}$

Then the problem becomes:

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3-5\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^2+1}-\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-5u+u^3}{u^3}}-\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}(1-5u+u^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[(1-5u+u^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[(1-\frac{5u}{3}+O(u^2))-1\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[-\frac{5u}{3}+O(u^2)\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(-\frac{5}{3}+O(u)\right)$$

$$=-\frac{5}{3}$$

EDIT: $$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[(1-5u+u^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\,\dbinom{\tfrac{1}{3}}{n}}({u^3-5u})^n\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\,\dbinom{\tfrac{1}{3}}{n}}({u^3-5u})^n\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{u}\left[\frac{1}{3}(u^3-5u) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\,\dbinom{\tfrac{1}{3}}{n}}u^n({u^2-5})^n\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{3}(u^2-5) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\,\dbinom{\tfrac{1}{3}}{n}}u^{n-1}({u^2-5})^n\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{3}u^2-\frac{5}{3} + u\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\,\dbinom{\tfrac{1}{3}}{m+2}}u^{m}({u^2-5})^{m+2}\right]\right)$$

$$=-\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Perfect and exactly as demanded in question (although we don't really need infinite series as mentioned in question rather we need adequate number of terms of Taylor expansions with error term expressed in small-o/big-o notation like you have done I  your answer). +1

Comment: The only actual question is the body of the problem is: "what is the idea to solving with infinite series?"

Answer (score 0):

In this resolution, "infinite" is not essential. What matters is to find an approximation of the expression that yields the same limit while leading to tractable computation.

The royal path to such approximation is the Taylor theorem, which establishes polynomial approximations to functions, around a chosen point.

It suffices to limit the development to a small number of terms to be conclusive about the limit. (See the explanation by @FlameTrap.)

---

IMO, the reference to infinite series is an amalgam with entire series, somehow related to the Taylor series.